# get numbers from left to right

Tags: sql, oracle

Ive a diary where every page contains only single topic, not more than that

Input

```
PageNum | Title
1| A
2| B
4| C
5| D
7| E
```

want to read the book from left to right ( page 0 to page last), show null where there is no topic on page

```
left | right
null | A              /0,1
B    | null           /2,3
C    | D              /4,5
null | E              /6,7
```

So its a sequence from 0 to last page from left to right
Kinda stuck to think  how it can be solved ? any suggestions please

Comment: Self FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh, how it'll work to get expected output with full outer join ?

Comment: @Oxana Grey: select the even numbers, select the odd numbers, full outer join on odd = even + 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can skip entire double pages then you need a row generator to include the missing pages and can use:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE MOD(p.pagenum, 2) WHEN 0 THEN t.title END) AS left,
       MAX(CASE MOD(p.pagenum, 2) WHEN 1 THEN t.title END) AS right,
       LISTAGG(p.pagenum, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.pagenum) AS pages
FROM   (
         SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS pagenum
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT CEIL(MAX(pagenum+1)/2)*2 FROM table_name)
       ) p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       ON (p.pagenum = t.PageNum)
GROUP BY
       FLOOR(p.pagenum/2)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (PageNum, Title) AS
SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'F' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | LEFT | RIGHT | PAGES |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | *null* | A | 0,1 |
> | B | *null* | 2,3 |
> | C | D | 4,5 |
> | *null* | E | 6,7 |
> | *null* | *null* | 8,9 |
> | F | *null* | 10,11 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0002a9cb7b1574c51ef9f47ee6282af6)*

Answer (score 2):

Group by page number integer-divided by 2 to get the pairs.

```
select
  max(case when mod(pagenum, 2) = 0 then title end) as title_left,
  max(case when mod(pagenum, 2) = 1 then title end) as title_right
from mytable
group by trunc(pagenum / 2)
order by trunc(pagenum / 2);
```

The `MAX` is needed, because the DBMS does not know that there is only up to one row matching the modulo expression. You could just as well use `MIN`. It makes no difference. Use `ANY_VALUE` here, if you are alreay using Oracle 21c.

Here is the outer join solution that jarlh suggested in the comments:

```
with even as (select * from mytable where mod(pagenum, 2) = 0)
   , odd  as (select * from mytable where mod(pagenum, 2) = 1)
select
  even.title as title_left,
  odd.title as title_right
from even full outer join odd on odd.pagenum = even.pagenum + 1
order by coalesce(even.pagenum, odd.pagenum);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=852cc5f8d45da8e832e44a9a48269c76

Comment: dont think so your solution will work if input data set has last record like 20, ZZ, it wont so null | null for all combinations  upto 21

Comment: As the demo fiddle shows, my query works well for the sample data. If there are complete double pages missing from the table then these won't be shown, because there is no title to display and it wasn't explicitly requested to show such pages. MT0's and Marmite Bomber's queries partly meet this additional requirement of showing empty double pages. That is, they show empty double pages in between, but not at the end, because the data doesn't tell us how many pages the book actually has.

Answer (score 1):

Create first the page *skelett* of the book.
Easy task for `connect by level`only the boundary must be set carefully.

```
select
 2*(rownum-1) left, 2*rownum-1 right
from dual connect by level <= (select ceil(max(pageNum+1)/2) from table_name); 

      LEFT      RIGHT
---------- ----------
         0          1
         2          3
         4          5
         6          7
         8          9
        10         11
```

Than use it simple with two `outer joins`:

```
with book as(         
select
 2*(rownum-1) left, 2*rownum-1 right
from dual connect by level <= (select ceil(max(pageNum+1)/2) from table_name)
)
select 
lt.Title title_left, rt.Title title_right
from book
left outer join table_name lt on book.left = lt.pageNum
left outer join table_name rt on book.right = rt.pageNum
order by left;
```